# A specific sort of Objects according to a parameter within *ngFor

Tags: html, algorithm, loops, angular, ngfor

My issue is caused by a lack in experience with angular2 and HTML5 so dont blame me please ;)
I have some food categories like this: [image]

Here is their HTML :

```
<div
  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
  class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 lc-reset-padding-v"
>
  <md-card>
    <md-card-title-group>
      <md-card-title layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <div class="md-card-title-media inline">
          <img
            alt="{{item.picture.alt}}"
            title="{{item.picture.title}}"
            src="{{page_items_url + item.picture.public_id}}"
          >
        </div>
        <div class="md-card-title-text inline">
          <span class="md-headline inline">{{item.name}}</span>
          <span *ngIf="item?.internal_reference">
          <p class="md-headline-reference">
           {{'ref' | translate}}: {{item.internal_reference | truncate : 22}}
          </p>
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="item?.description">
          <p class="md-subhead">{{item.description | truncate : 100}}</p>
          </span>
          <span
            *ngIf="page?.advanced"
            class="label label-pill item-type text-capitalize">
            {{item.item_type || 'no type for this '}} item
          </span>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="item.out_of_stock" class="ribbon">
          <span>{{'notAvailable' | translate}}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="price">
          {{item.price | currency: item.official_currency:true:'1.2-3'}}
        </span>
      </md-card-title>
    </md-card-title-group>
  </md-card>
</div>
```

Each one of these food types belongs to a `category` (illustrated as an object parameter in each food object), So I want that the View of foods will be ordered by categories like this one: [image]

I added these lines within the `*ngFor` loop:

```
<h3 class="text-muted text-uppercase title-container">
                  {{item.category.name}}
        </h3>
```

But, -and logically-, it appeared like this :

[image]

Any Help or guidance or ideas Please ?

Comment: What's your question / issue.

Comment: `So I want that the View of foods will be ordered by categories like this one: `.... second picture ..

Comment: This is not related to Angular nor HTML, it's pure algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Sakuto said in the comments, this is not related to HTML or Angular, its a problem in your logic.

You are trying to create a list by iterating with `*ngFor` through all the items.

What you want to achieve is to create different lists by category.

You have 2 solutions, or you change your data to be category driven instead of item driven, or you group your items by category.

So if you change your data, your object would look something like this:

```
interface FoodList {
  categories: Category[];
}
interface Category {
  name: string;
  items: FoodItem[];
}
interface FoodItem {
  //your item
}
```

And then on the list you do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of yourCategories">
   <h5>{{category.name}}</h5>
   <div *ngFor="let item of category.items">
      {{item.name}}
      <!-- your item template --> 
   </div>
</div>
```

If you aren't able to change your data model, just group your items by category before "printing" it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to Angular but it's directly related to an algorithm problem, what you want can be done in two differents way:

1. Retrieve the products ordered bt the category name, then just check if the previous category name is different than the current, if yes, print the category name, otherwise just print the product. Here's an explanation in pseudo code.

   ```
   var currentCategoryName = "";
   FOR product in products
       IF product.categoryName != currentCategoryName
           WRITE product.categoryName
       ENDIF

       WRITE product
   ENDFOR
   ```
2. Second way, if you can't order them or do not want to, you could just create a new collection where each category would have its element.

   ```
   var yourList = [];

   FOR product in products
       yourList[product.categoryName][] = product
   ENDFOR

   // Display
   FOR category in yourList
       WRITE category[0].categoryName

       FOR product in category
           WRITE product
       ENDFOR
   ENDFOR
   ```